Error when a plugin is installed on Etherpad
Downloaded the latest version of Etherpad and tried to install a plugin.
bellow error when installed:
[2024-04-03T16:40:26.259] [INFO] plugins - Successfully installed plugin ep_allmende
[2024-04-03T16:40:26.260] [INFO] plugins - Loading plugin ep_allmende...
[2024-04-03T16:40:26.261] [INFO] plugins - Loading plugin ep_etherpad-lite...
[2024-04-03T16:40:26.261] [INFO] plugins - Loaded 2 plugins
[2024-04-03T16:40:26.263] [ERROR] settings - Failed to load hook function "src/plugin_packages/ep_allmende/allmende:eejsBlock_scripts" for plugin "ep_allmende" part "ep_allmende" hook set "hooks" hook "eejsBlock_scripts": Error: Not a function
    at Object.extractHooks (/src/static/js/pluginfw/shared.js:57:28)
    at exports.update (/src/static/js/pluginfw/plugins.js:115:28)
    at async onAllTasksFinished (/src/static/js/pluginfw/installer.ts:2:2275)


below error in restart:
[2024-04-03T16:47:40.873] [ERROR] settings - Failed to load hook function "/Users/sriserineni/sri/corp/silver/product/dev/silver-web/silver-pad-4/src/plugin_packages/ep_allmende/allmende:eejsBlock_scripts" for plugin "ep_allmende" part "ep_allmende" hook set "hooks" hook "eejsBlock_scripts": Error: Not a function
    at Object.extractHooks (/src/static/js/pluginfw/shared.js:57:28)
    at exports.update (/src/static/js/pluginfw/plugins.js:115:28)
    at async exports.start (/src/node/server.ts:6:1373)
[2024-04-03T16:47:40.883] [ERROR] settings - Failed to load hook function "/src/plugin_packages/ep_openid_connect:authenticate" for plugin "ep_openid_connect" part "main" hook set "hooks" hook "authenticate": Error: Cannot find module 'uri-js'


Happening for any plugin.
Node version: v21.7.2
pnpm -v 8.15.5
npm -v: 10.5.0
Etheroad -v: 2.0.1
installed plugin ep_etherpad-lite, ep_allmende.
